# Wordpress 4.3 broke meta redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, url-parameters

I'm using the plugin URL Params ([homepage](http://www.asandia.com/wordpress-plugins/urlparams/)) in order to send an URL to a page and after three seconds redirect the user to that page. Unfortunately Wordpress 4.3 broke that functionality.

This is how it was done:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=[urlparam param="link"]">
```

The redirect only redirects the user to http://www.sitename.com/redirect/[urlparam%20param=

A work around is putting a link and placing it like this but then I loose the auto redirect.

```
<a href='[urlparam param="link"]'>
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite the meta tag so that the redirect could work?

Comment: Might be better at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank's I will do that.